# Visual Studio 2010 crashes upon editing a C# string literal

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, resharper

My VS2010 Premium RTM installation has developed a nasty habit of crashing when I edit a string literal. It 'feels' like the Intellisense bug and I have an unreasonable and unsupported hunch that this has something to do with ReSharper, because the ReSharper integrations get slower and slower until finally the crash happens when I edit a string literal.

This is happening on two seperate PCs so it is not PC-specific. My R# build is: 5.1.1751.8 dated 2010-08-31.

Anyone else seeing this? Any insight?

Comment: Have you tried disabling ReSharper?

Comment: I have now. I used VS for nearly two days without a crash. I've now re-enabled R# again and am already experiencing instabilities, although the crash-on-literal-string-edit hasn't returned.

Comment: Are you using a large solution, or editing large files?