# Visual Studio 2010 Crashes after pasting a large multi-line string (Approximately 1500 lines)

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crash

I am creating a VB application in Visual Studio 2010 that installs some SQL stored procedures. These stored procedures are encrypted otherwise I would just supply my clients with .sql files to create the stored procedures.

The install script that creates the stored procedure is 1500 lines in length and has been formatted in the way VS 2010 requires multi-line literals to be in:

```
"First Line" & _  
"Second Line" & _  
"etc..."
```

Every time I paste the multi-line script into Visual Studio the application crashes. Anyone have better way of assigning a very large string literal to a string variable. What I require is the following:

```
Imports System.Data.Sql Client
```

...

```
cmd cmd as SqlCommand
dim str as string

str = _
    "Very" & _
    "Long" & _
    ... 1500 lines ...
    "String"

cmd.CommandText = str
```

or some other way of assigning a .sql script to a SqlCommand.

Thanks.

Comment: Were you using ReSharper when you experienced this? I've just experienced something similar, and uninstalling ReSharper made the problem go away. I wonder if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886116/visual-studio-2010-crashes-upon-editing-a-c-sharp-string-literal) might be the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could either paste it in Notepad and save it there, or split it in multiple strings that you just concatenate at the end.

Or even better, put the command in a resource file and load the resource at run time!

Comment: I can open the .vb file using notepad++ and paste the string without issue. But if i open the solution in VS2010, it crashes shortly after loading the solution.

Comment: I am interested in your comment about saving the string as a resource and loading at runtime, could you walk me through how to do that?

Comment: You simply right click your project, go to resources and add your code under a key name. If that still fails because it's too big (it might), you do it manually in the `properties/resources.resx` file (it's just xml, make sure you escape any `<>&` characters properly).

Comment: The difference being that you never actually load `resources.resx` in the vs editor, it just gets added as a resource blob to your project by `csc.exe`, so it should be safe once entered externally.

Comment: After I have added my long formatted string to the resources how do i assign the string to my variable?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk.aspx should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I added the string to the projects resources and use the code provided in the MSDN article I get the following error: "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "items.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "<PROJECT NAME>" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

Comment: I had the wrong name for the resource file. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this Problem too and the following code works for me:

```
cmd cmd as SqlCommand
dim str as string

str = "Very" 
str &= "Long" 
    ... 1500 lines ...
str &= "String"

cmd.CommandText = str
```

I hope it helps.